# In Hibernate, can you have a composite key where one value is database generated

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a database with a table with a composite key, where one of the values is generated in the database and the other is set based on a parent class. I'm trying to implement this in hibernate. I've seen a large number of contradictory articles with this, possibly based on different versions. For Hibernate 4.3, how can I do this?

Here's the solution that seems to make the most sense but it doesn't work. The big limitation on the database is that the key to be generated shouldn't be passed in the insert

inside maillists class

```
     @EmbeddedId
     @AttributeOverrides( {
     @AttributeOverride(name="mailLists", column=@Column(name="Mail_Lists", nullable=false) ), 
     @AttributeOverride(name="ien", column=@Column(name="IEN", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false) ) } )
     public MailListsSubscriberId getId() {
         return this.id;
     }
```

separate Composite ID class

```
@Embeddable
public class MailListsSubscriberId  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private int mailLists;
 private int ien;

 @Column(name="Mail_Lists", nullable=false)
 public int getMailLists() {
    return this.mailLists;
 }

 ...    

 @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
 @Column(name="IEN", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
 public int getIen() {
    return this.ien;
 }
...
```

Log

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class edu.ucdavis.vmth.vmacs.persistence.model.MailListsSubscriber
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:120)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:271)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:251)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:189)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:886)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:868)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:277)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:474)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:343)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:186)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your database model is incorrect and won't work with hibernate or any other ORM as it is. The hint is in something you said in your question

> The big limitation on the database is that the key to be generated shouldn't be passed in the update

That means that the generated column is not part of the key, otherwise you would need it, otherwise it's not part of the identifier.

If you want to read about why this is the case, you can read about the [Object-Relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch#Philosophical_differences).

If you're dealing with a poor designed legacy schema and you cannot change it, I would suggest to drop hibernate and use something like MyBatis.

## Edit

Ok, after the clarification that the key cannot be passed on the *insert* rather than *update*, there's a solution (which I've never used, so hopefully it will work). Hibernate supports a type of *generator* called [`select`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-select) which is there for this kind of situation.

For example, you can try annotating the `ien` column with the following (the example is taken from the [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e2628))

```
@Id
private int mailLists;

@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="trigger-generated")
@GenericGenerator(
    name="trigger-generated", 
    strategy = "select",
    parameters = @Parameter(name="key", value = "surrogateIdColumnName")
)
private String ien;
```

The *odd* thing, is that for hibernate to be able to retrieve the generated key, it needs to select the row... and to do that, it needs to know of another column to be used as a surrogate key. In the example above, the table must have a column named `surrogateIdColumnName` which is unique.

Ideally, if you could update the schema, it would be better to assign the table a single id column with an auto increment value, and make this other key (mailList + ien) a unique key.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of OR impedance mismatch you are concerned about. Also, it is possible to have a key that is generated by the database, my maillist actually does it using @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) on its int id, and when that happens there is no "id=" in the generated update.

Comment: I realized I mispoke in the post, it should be: The big limitation on the database is that the key to be generated shouldn't be passed in the *insert*

Comment: That makes a world of difference :). I know from the documentation that there's a way to do this with the `select` strategy for the `Generated` value. I'll update the answer with what I know, but I've never used this... so I'm not 100% sure if it works.

Comment: Augusto, I've banged my head on this pretty hard, if you have some insight that would be wonderful

Comment: Could you post the table DDL (including indexes)?

Comment: This is a very valid answer, but the addition of the other column doesn't work for us. Thanks still! The banged my head comment was because I didn't see the edit.